Ubuntu VNC failing to connect after Nvidia driver update
I am using Real VNC to connect to an Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. Yesterday, I updated the Nvidia drivers to version 535 and ran sudo reboot. Since then, however, I am unable to connect to the desktop, with it saying "RealVNC Server is not currently listening for cloud connections."
How can I fix this?
